# Hide SMS message in notification bar

Tags: sms, notifications, notification-bar

I am using Moto E powered by Android Kitkat.

When I receive an SMS, I get a notification displaying the sender name with the message. I don't want the message text to be displayed in the notification, just the sender name is enough.

How can I prevent the message text from being displayed?

NOTE: I don't want to stop the notification. I just want to hide the text message in the notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GoSMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) has a "Notification bar privacy mode" option, which 'shows "New Message" instead of the message's content'.

[image: Sliding SMS Privacy Mode]

I personally use [Sliding SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smitten.slidingmms) (which is a standalone app created for and taken from CyanogenMod 10). It has an option to enable "Privacy Mode", which hides the sender and message from the status bar notification. 8sms (which is also from CM10 M2) also has this option.

[image: Sliding SMS Privacy Mode]

Answer (score 1):

Third party sms app like [Handcent SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) ,[8sms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkleft.eightyeightsms.mms) and [Go sms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) etc have option to hide the notification message from the status bar.

Just go to these sms app. In settings you will find option to hide the message content in notification bar.

Answer (score 0):

[Chomp SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.p1.chompsms) also works fine. We can choose what to display in the notification bar. In privacy mode, we can hide name, text and both.